# Open link in new tab with cmd-key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, keyboard

I'm using this to click on an element to open a link. Is there a way to make it open a new tab when I hold the cmd-key down (and whatever that reflects in other OS)?

```
$(document).on('click', '.row', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = '?id=' + $(this).data('id');
});
```

Basically the way a normal `<a>` works but via JS.

Comment: `window.open(url)` for new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.row', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (cmd) window.open('?id=' + $(this).data('id'), "_blank");
  else window.location = '?id=' + $(this).data('id');
});
var cmd = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 91 || key == 93 || key == 17 || key == 224) cmd = true;
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  cmd = false;
});
```

```css
.row { border: 1px #000 solid }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Doesn't seem to work in Firefox on Mac but Safari and Chrome. Good enough for me!

Comment: Test it to see if it works now on Firefox, but also others because it could've changed the status. It just added the key = e.which || e.keyCode because which doesn't work on firefox I think, just keyCode. I can change it back if it doesn't work so it will work for others viewing it.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. Still works in Safari and Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the window opens in a new window without cmd-clicking. This often happens when I return to Chrome after doing some other stuff. If I refresh the page it disappears, Is it a bug or something that can be fixed in the code? Thanks!

Comment: SeaBass, I don't believe that it can be fixed in code. It might just be a browser issue or setting.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need to keep track of whether your target key(s) are being pressed in addition to your click handler:

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(cmdPressed) {
      console.log('new tab');
      // window.open('');
  } else {
      console.log('redirect');
      // location.href = '';
  }
})

// keeps track of whether user is pressing cmd key
var cmdPressed = false;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    cmdPressed = e.which === 91;
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    cmdPressed = false;
});
```

```html
<div id="test">
Click or CMD+Click me
</div>
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if(cmdPressed) {
      console.log('new tab');
      // window.open('');
   } else {
      console.log('redirect');
      // location.href = '';
   }
});

// keeps track of whether user is pressing cmd key
var cmdPressed = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    cmdPressed = e.which === 91;
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    cmdPressed = false;
});
```